# How to use ".dll" and ".lib" files in DevCpp projects?

Tags: c++, linker, mingw, dev-c++

I'm trying to use a library named *crypto* in my DevCpp project:

[image]

To do so, I've added the library files to the "Linker Parameters" and also the project's directory to the "Library, Include and Resources directories" in the "Project Options" as below:

[image]

[image]

Finally, I've imported the header file in the main.cpp file and I called a function from the library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <crypto.h>

int main() {
    void * ctx;
    initGP(&ctx, 0, (char *)"123456", (char *)"123456", (char *)"TEST");
    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to compile the code, I face the Undefined Reference error for the library function in the link time:

[image]

My makefile:

```
# Project: Project1
# Makefile created by Dev-C++ 5.11

CPP      = g++.exe
CC       = gcc.exe
WINDRES  = windres.exe
OBJ      = main.o
LINKOBJ  = main.o
LIBS     = -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib32" -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib32" -static-libgcc -L"C:/Users/user/Desktop/prj"  crypto.dll crypto.lib -m32
INCS     = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include" -I"C:/Users/user/Desktop/prj"
CXXINCS  = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++" -I"C:/Users/user/Desktop/prj"
BIN      = Project1.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) -m32
CFLAGS   = $(INCS) -m32
RM       = rm.exe -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

clean: clean-custom
    ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CPP) -c main.cpp -o main.o $(CXXFLAGS)
```

**Quetion: what's wrong and how can I fix the issue?**

Comment: The libraries you are using may be compiled for msvc / Visual Studio and not work with mingw. With  Visual Studio you would link with the .lib (import library) file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't link the `.dll`, you link the library and keep the `.dll` next to your executable. The error you're seeing is most likely because it can't determine what kind of a library is a `.dll` file.

Also, `.lib` files are MSVC libraries. gcc expects `.a`, `.o` or `.so`.

Comment: Thank you. How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Either download mingw binaries or build cryptopp from sources.